# Centreon API Error: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

Tags: python

I'm simply trying to authenticate to Centreon API so that I can get the API token.  I am running this python script on the Centreon server itself, but it fails. Has anybody worked with this api before?  Anything I need to change in the code?

```
import requests

requests.get('http://api.mydomain.tld/api/index.php?action=authenticate', auth=('my_username', 'my_password'))
```

Edit:
Here is the output I recieve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 4, in <module>
    requests.get('http://api.domain.com.tld/api/index.php?action=authenticate', auth=('user', 'password'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 68, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
```

Comment: Can you share a stack trace and the content of the response? Is it a 403, 404, 500 etc?

Comment: I'm not getting any numbered errors.  I added what the output is above.

Comment: The username and the password should be parameters of the request as stated in the documentation of the API. As far as I understand, you use a parameter "auth"